# Microsoft Azureクラウドサービスサービス構成ファイルの取得方法

Tags: azure

Microsoft Azure クラウドサービスに固定IP（予約済みIP）を設定したく調査したところ、
サービス構成ファイルに予約済みIPを指定することで固定IPが設定できるとの情報を得ました。
https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

さらに、サービス構成ファイルの編集方法について以下のサイトを確認したのですが、
http://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-configure/
管理ポータルのクラウドサービスの画面に「構成」のタブが見当たりません。
「構成」タブは廃止されてしまったのでしょうか。

サービス構成ファイルを取得するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。
また、この方法以外で固定IPを設定する方法があればご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

使われているサービスが「仮想マシン」であれば構成タブはありません。
※ややこしいのですが仮想マシンを作った場合でもクラウドサービスは作成されます

仮想マシンの場合で予約済みIPアドレスを利用する場合は、同じURLの上部の仮想マシンの場合にやり方が記載されています。
https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

現状、Azure PowerShellを使用して設定する形になるかと思います。